# How to meet multi condition with data.table in more graceful way?

Tags: r, data.table

Here is the toy sample including 2 character variables. I have another vector of  two characters. By comparing one by one, I can get the result, but is there more  graceful way of doing it?

```
set.seed(100)
DT <- data.table(V1 = LETTERS[sample(1:5, 10, replace = T)], 
                 V2 = LETTERS[sample(3:7, 10, replace = T)])
V1V2 = c("B", "G")
DT[V1 %in% V1V2[1] & V2 %in% V1V2[2]]
#    V1 V2
# 1:  B  G
```

Since we can directly get the row elements by `apply` with `DT[apply(DT[,.(V1, V2)], 1,  print)]` There shall be a way to describe a multi-condition express in `i`.

I'm expecting something like:

```
DT[.(V1, V2) %in% V1V2]
```

but this seems not to be working.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use the join-capabilities of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
setkey(DT, V1, V2)
DT[as.list(V1V2)]
```

or:

```
DT[as.list(V1V2), on = .(V1, V2)]
```

Comment: I'm thinking of merge way. WIl feed back later once I finish my expriment. Thanks!

Comment: setDT extraneous here :)

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thx & updated. I thought it was needed because using `.(V1V2)` didn't work.

Comment: yep... as.list is necessary to turn c('B','G') into list('B','G'), vs list(c('B','G'))

Answer (score 2):

We could use `as.list` to compare column-wise every element in `V1V2`

```
DT  == as.list(V1V2)

#       V1    V2
# [1,]  TRUE FALSE
# [2,]  TRUE  TRUE
# [3,] FALSE FALSE
# [4,] FALSE FALSE
# [5,] FALSE FALSE
# [6,] FALSE FALSE
# [7,] FALSE FALSE
# [8,]  TRUE FALSE
# [9,] FALSE FALSE
#[10,] FALSE FALSE
```

This compares `V1V2[1]` with 1st column of `DT` and `V1V2[2]` with second column.

Now select rows where all elements are `TRUE`

```
DT[rowSums(DT  == as.list(V1V2)) == ncol(DT), ]
#   V1 V2
#1:  B  G
```